# Change Unicode to Str returns "not supported"

Tags: python, python-3.x, email, character-encoding, decode

In the program code is "unicode is not defined" returned. A change from unicode to str returns "str is not supported". What is wrong or missing?

```
for header in [ 'subject' ]:
    dh = email.header.decode_header(msg[header])
    default_charset = 'ASCII'
    print('%-8s: %s' % (header.upper(), ''.join([ unicode(t[0], t[1] or default_charset) for t in dh ])))
```

Answer (score 0):

The [unicode](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#unicode) builtin function does not exist in Python 3 - this is why you get the exception `NameError: name 'unicode' is not defined`.  In Python 3 the equivalent of `unicode` is [str](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-str).

Like `unicode`, `str` accepts an encoding argument and will try to decode a bytestring using the provided encoding.  If you pass a `str` instance to `str` for decoding you will get `TypeError: decoding str is not supported`.

The output of [email.header.decode_header](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.header.html#email.header.decode_header) could include both `str` and `bytes` instances, so your comprehension needs to be able to handle both:

```
print('%-8s: %s' % ('subject'.upper(), ''.join(t[0] if isinstance(t[0], str) else str(t[0], t[1] or default_charset) for t in dh)))
```

(In Python 3 it's probably best to set default_charset to 'utf-8').

Finally, if you control how the message object is being created, you can have the headers automatically decoded by specifying a policy object when creating the message (Python 3.5+).

```
>>> from email.policy import default
>>> with open('message.eml', 'rb') as f:
...     msg = email.message_from_bytes(f.read(), policy=default)
>>>

>>> for x in msg.raw_items():print(x)
... 
('Subject', 'Ayons asperges pour le =?utf-8?q?d=C3=A9jeuner?=')
('From', '=?utf-8?q?Pep=C3=A9?= Le Pew <pepe@example.com>')
('To', 'Penelope Pussycat <penelope@example.com>,\n Fabrette Pussycat <fabrette@example.com>')
('Content-Type', 'text/plain; charset="utf-8"')
('Content-Transfer-Encoding', 'quoted-printable')
('MIME-Version', '1.0')
>>> msg['from']
'Pepé Le Pew <pepe@example.com>'
>>> msg['subject']
'Ayons asperges pour le déjeuner'
```

(Message data taken from the email [examples](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.examples.html)).